# How to access object in S3 to upload file using presigned url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Because I have many objects name by task id, and i want to upload the file to the directory of a task id spec can be added.
I can get path of the object by task_id and timestamp of this task. I have read reference `generate_presigned_post` but I couldn't generate presigned url by this path obj.
So, i want to support any ideas???

How to generate presigned url by this path obj to upload file in S3

Comment: Pre-signed URLs are for objects and require the bucket and full key of the object. Either auto-generate the full key of the object and pre-sign that or if you want the client to have some control over the key then provide the client with an API that allows them to request a specific key and then your server pre-signs that (after validating it).

Comment: S3 has no concept of a "folder".  It does have common prefixes among some items, but this only has meaning to the ListObjects APIs.  POST Object needs a full and complete object name, and thus the presigned variant needs the object name as well.

Comment: @jarmod example: i have object /a/b/test.zip in S3, but i want to access /a/b/ where I can upload file. So any idea? Thanks

Comment: You can't.  The only thing you can do with a shared prefix is list the objects in it.

Comment: @AnonCoward I have a situation where I have uploaded the file in s3, and now I want to update the file another into that object, is there any way to handle this situation?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. You have a ZIP file in S3 and you want to modify the ZIP file by adding an additional file to it? You can't modify objects in S3. You have to replace them. If you simply want to add a new object beneath `a/b/` (note: it's not `/a/b/`) then decide what key suffix you want (e.g. dog.png) and pre-sign the full key (`a/b/dog.png`).

Comment: @jarmod If i simply want to add a new object same your idea, have  you example detail for it ?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, there are technically no folders in S3 so uploading to a folder is not possible. What we see as folders in the console are simply prefixes to the object name that make for easier organization. When you generate a presigned URL, it's for a single object, and the object key you provide should contain the full path with these "folder" prefixes. For example, `somefolder/somefile.jpg`. So if you want to use presigned URLs, you will have to cycle through each filename with the prefix you want.

A possible alternative is the [S3 TransferManager API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3-transfermanager.html) in the AWS SDK for Java. This will let you upload multiple files or even directories to S3, but doesn't use presigned URLs.

Comment: If you want to use Transfer Manager, be sure to use AWS SDK for Java V2. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/introducing-amazon-s3-transfer-manager-in-the-aws-sdk-for-java-2-x/?sc_channel=sm&sc_campaign=Developer_Blog&sc_publisher=TWITTER&sc_country=SDK&sc_geo=GLOBAL&sc_outcome=awareness&trk=na_TWITTER